# Nutch- how to delete old segments?

Tags: solr, hadoop, nutch

In nutch, when I crawl and then re-crawl, duplicated segments are created.
how can I delete the old ones?

I can't know for sure that only the segments that were created in the latest crawl are used and all the others can be deleted, can I?

Answer (score 1):

```
I can't know for sure that only the segments that were created in the latest crawl are used and all the others can be deleted, can I?
```

The segments created in the last crawl are useful and others can be deleted.

Comment: Why isn't there a setting that allows to automatically delete old segments?